# Is it possible to have multiple clickable icons in single cell on ag grid table in angular 6?

Tags: angular6, ag-grid

I need to place three clickable icons in a table cell in ag-grid table.I am using angular6 in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

there are two ways how we can do it:
it is properties of `columnDefs`

1) `cellRendererSelector`

2) `cellRendererFramework`

HERE PLNKR link: https://plnkr.co/edit/9woOFZL5uvIuyW363Xzy?p=preview

Here we have defined renderFrameWork wich accept whole component where we have three button in one cell

```
            {
                headerName: "Clickable Component",
                field: "name",
                cellRendererFramework: ClickableParentComponent,
                width: 330
            }
```

[image]

Below you can see defined component of cell

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ag-clickable',
    template: `
        <button style="height: 21px;WIDTH:50PX" (click)="click()" class="btn btn-info">Click</button>
        <button style="height: 21px;WIDTH:50PX" (click)="click()" class="btn btn-info">Click</button>
        <button style="height: 21px;WIDTH:50PX" (click)="click()" class="btn btn-info">Click</button>
    `,
    styles: [
        `.btn {
            line-height: 0.5;
            width: 100%;
        }`
    ]
})
export class ClickableComponent {
    @Input() cell: any;
    @Output() onClicked = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    click(): void {
        this.onClicked.emit(this.cell);
    }
}
```

I RECCOMEND you first of all read the documentation about rendering of cell:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/

where you can find what you need